# Href links to subfolders

Tags: html, asp.net, web

I searched and feel this is an elementary questions but I can't think straight I guess.

So I have a simple subfolder in my website and pages I need to get to like this.

```
<a href="Default.aspx">Home</a>

<a href="Subfolder/help.aspx">Help</a>
```

So when I open my application, I go to the default page where I can click the Help page which takes me to the page in the subfolder, now, if I click on the Home link, it tries to take me to /subfolder/home.aspx ?

I understand what is doing but I don't know I can make the relative path work the way I want it. I can use absolute path but I should not.

Any help please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
<a href="~/Default.aspx" runat="server">Home</a>

<a href="~/Subfolder/help.aspx" runat="server">Help</a>
```

Now, each link will resolve on the server-side, from the project root downwards.

Comment: @causita you should accept this as the answer if it answered your question

Comment: What is this inclusion of a tilde in an href on an anchor?

Comment: the "~/" resolves from the project root.

Answer (score 2):

**Relative URLs** can be used when linking to pages within your own
website. They provide a shorthand way of telling the browser where to
find your files.

Repeat the `../` to indicate that you want to go up
folders, then follow it with the file name.
the code below makes the browser jump *one* folders back from the current folder (ie. that displays current webpage)

```
<a href="../home.aspx">Home</a>
```

Since you made a simple subfolder sstructure my guess is that one simple jump will provide the required page. you may jump back *two* folders using `../../` or *three* folders using `../../../` and so on until you reach the required folder containing your file.

Or you can use the root link which starts with `/`,
such links are know as root-relative links

```
<a href ="/home.aspx">Home</a>
```

more about relative links: http://www.motive.co.nz/glossary/linking.php?ref