# How to link html pages in nested folders?

Tags: html

Suppose I have my main page with all the links in parent folder shown as -
parent/mainpage.html
Now if I have the linked pages in directory parent/subdir1/subdir2/otherpage.html

In this case how do I provide the value of otherpage.html in href of mainpage.html ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Href links to subfolders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24275712/href-links-to-subfolders)

Comment: otherpage.html: `subdir1/subdir2/otherpage.html`, mainpage.html: `../../mainpage.html`

Comment: Already tried subdir1/subdir2/otherpage.html and ../../mainpage.html. Both did not work.

Answer (score 0):

I think **parent** is your main directory folder?  right?

If I am not wrong you can link pages manually like this:

```
include_once( "/parent/subdir1/subdir2/otherpage.html" );
```

Or if you don't want to link menually then you can also link pages using `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` function. It provides the URL of your **project root directory** after that you can create a path as you want..

Like this:

```
include_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/subdir1/subdir2/otherpage.html");
```

Please try this and let me know if it's working or not?